# Посыл системе сообщений с помощью MMDevice

Tags: c++, c, winapi, аудио, mmdevice

Хотелось бы узнать, отправляет ли данное API сообщения в winapi процедуру?
Что пытаюсь сделать: в бесконечном цикле(ну, вы понимаете) идет постоянное получение свойств звукового устройства текущего(конкретно - количество его разъемов). Нагрузка на процессор есть, бесконечный цикл дает своё. Вот и хотелось бы узнать, может есть сообщения, которые стоит ловить, и это облегчит жизнь процессора. Спасибо.

```
....
UINT jacks = 0;

HRESULT hr = pPart->Activate(CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IKsJackDescription), (void**)&pJackDesc);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    std::wcout << L"IKsJackDescription failed: " << hr << std::endl;
    this->ClearEtcetera();
    return false;
}

// получаем количество разъемов
hr = pJackDesc->GetJackCount(&jacks);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    std::wcout << L"GetJackCount failed\n";
    this->ClearEtcetera();
}
//std::wcout << L"Jack count: " << jacks << std::endl << std::endl;
```

P.S.: Этот код и еще выше(его прилично) находится в while(true).

Comment: А добавьте туда Sleep(10) хотя бы. Нагрузка упадет сильно, а 10 мс никто и не заметит.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не костыль случаем? Просто вдруг именно в эти 10 мс произойдёт изменение...конечно, вероятность мала, но вдруг? Но я попробую.

Comment: Костыль, но если нет Wait-функций - что делать? Изменение может произойти и вы его получите через 10 мс. Вероятность того, что изменение будет актуально только в эти 10 мс - IMHO нулевая...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов обязательно отпишусь о результатах:)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не уверен точно, но кажется нашёл то, что нужно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd371417(v=vs.85).aspx
<< OnDeviceStateChanged

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ан нет. Нет события изменения устройства...https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd370823(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Попробуйте вот это: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371088(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Что касается периодического опроса, получение информации о разъемах довольно тяжелая операция, которая задействует в том числе реестр. Вызывать ее с интервалом в 10 мс, конечно, не стоит. Минимум 250 мс где-то нужно брать.

Comment: @VadimTagil вот, я же не просто так задал вопрос. Под отладкой вычислял, считал..и дела плохи, все обходится дорого.

Comment: @VadimTagil опробую Вашу ссылку, спасибо

Comment: Sleep прекрасно справился со своей задачей, это гениальный приём. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Команда `Sleep` поможет оптимизировать код.